# Web packaging using web.config transformation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, msbuild, web-deployment

I am planing to create a continuous Integration for MVC3 project. And here I am having several deployment strategies(Eg: Debug,Staging,Release). I want to package deploy-able Zip files for each configuration.

When i try msbuild command for web packaging with web.config transformation it create zip file with 
`connectionString="$(ReplacableToken_ExileLibraryDbContext-Web.config Connection String_0)"/>`

What I want is to create the zip file with the exact transformation. How can I do this ?

thanks

Comment: Are you going to be publishing with webdeploy from your CI server? If so, it will take care of the transform when it publishes it.  If not, take a look at this: http://sedodream.com/2011/12/24/PackageOncePublishAnywhere.aspx it may help you with what you want